# What is a good network graph library for language X?

Tags: language-agnostic, graph, graph-theory

I have noticed that a recurring question is: “What is a good network graph library for language X”. I have played with quite a few of the libraries and I can share my experiences with you.

**Python**:
[NetworkX](https://networkx.org) is a robust library which has built-in visualization but also has an interface to [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org) using [pyGraphviz](https://pygraphviz.github.io). (pyGraphviz and NetworkX are written by the same author). NetworkX is open source and a very easy to use.

**Perl**:
[Circos](http://mkweb.bcgsc.ca/circos/) is developed to visualize genomes and other highly complex datasets. It will always use a circular layout but that it often the most appropriate layout if your network is really large and its ‘modularity’ score is low.  Circos is open source.

.**Net**:
[NodeXL](http://www.codeplex.com/NodeXL) is developed by Microsoft Research and is both an add-on for Excel and a .Net 3.5 library. It’s pretty open (for Microsoft’s standards) and uses Fruchterman-Reingold algorithm for visualization.

**Java**:
[JUNG2](http://jung.sourceforge.net) has recently been released and is also a robust library. Has extended visualization and key metrics support.  JUNG2 is open source.

**UbiGraph**:
[UbiGraph](http://ubietylab.net/ubigraph/) has interfaces to different languages including Python (and NetworkX has UbiGraph support), Ruby, PHP, Java, C, C++, C#, Haskell, and OCaml. It has very neat 3D visualization of network graphs using an XML-RPC server. The basic version is free, you have to pay for the professional version.

**Standalone:**
You can always use an off-the-shelf package such as: [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org) (Win, Linux, OSX), [Pajek](http://vlado.fmf.uni-lj.si/pub/networks/pajek/) (Win), [UCINET](http://www.analytictech.com/downloaduc6.htm) (Win), or even Visio (Win).

I am sure there are many more packages, but these are the ones that I have used myself. What other libraries or packages are available?

Comment: SO is for questions. You don't state a question here, just a list. If you don't make this a community wiki it will certainly be closed as "not-a-question"

Comment: Add "Are there any others?" on the end of it ... There's your question. ;)

Comment: @lothar: I am a pretty new user to SO, and I just want to be of help. I am not sure if I can answer my own question and was not aware of the community wiki option. But I have changed it accordingly, so thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @DrDee Thanks for making it a community wiki. I think it's a useful list, that's why I tried to warn you (I recognized that you are new to SO; welcome).

Comment: I don't know what you guys are babbling about, surely:
" What other libraries or packages are available?"
is a question?!

Comment: Literally a question asking for specific information, with a relevant answer.

Answer (score 12):

You should add [graph-tool](http://graph-tool.skewed.de) to the python list. It is very complete, and it is implemented in C++, with the Boost Graph Library, making it orders of magnitude faster than python-only alternatives, such as NetworkX.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of graph-tool. :-)

Answer (score 2):

For **Clojure**, there is [loom](https://github.com/aysylu/loom). Its WIP but looks good.

Answer (score 2):

The [Stanford Network Analysis Project](http://snap.stanford.edu/) (SNAP) was written in C++ and designed with performance in mind to analyze large data sets. The project has been extended with a Python library, and it has comprehensive documentation.

Note also that the project is a good resource for [empirical data sets](http://snap.stanford.edu/data/index.html) from a variety of domains.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, prefuse is by far the best graph drawing package. It has a very fast force-directed layout algorithm, and since you can tweak the parameters in real time and drag nodes around to get the graph looking the way you want, you’ll be able to explore and arrange much larger graphs than with any non-interactive system.

Try out this [demo applet](http://prefuse.org/gallery/graphview/) and you’ll fall in love with it too...

Answer (score 0):

If you like the examples on [this page](http://www.research.att.com/~yifanhu/GALLERY/GRAPHS/index.html), take a look at Mathematica’s [graph plotting](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/GraphDrawing.html) capabilities. The author of the gallery page, Yifan Hu, used to work for Wolfram Research, where he developed graph drawing algorithms for enormous graphs. Those algorithms are now integrated into Mathematica. Depending on how you intend to use the graph drawings, you could get a huge benefit by being able to use Mathematica to analyse your graphs; see for example this [blog post](http://blog.wolfram.com/2007/08/05/the-equations-of-the-bridge/).

Answer (score 0):

[yFiles](http://www.yworks.com/yfiles) is a suite of layout algorithms that offers the broadest range of different automatic sophisticated layout styles. It's a commercial offering and is available for several popular platforms and languages: Javascript, Java, C#, and more.

There is an [interactive online demo that shows many of the available algorithms](http://live.yworks.com/demobrowser/#Layout-Styles) and the libraries can be evaluated for free.

<sup>Disclaimer: I work for the company that creates these libraries, however on SO I do not represent my employer. This recommendation is based on my own opinion. I have seen many different layout suite implementations for the above languages in the last 15 years and I don't know of any other implementation available that is as complete and extensible as this one.</sup>